# Is it legal to use template class name in derived class without template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, c++17

The following code compiles fine both with [*clang++ 8.0.0*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GmcHFg8H1S6Oab15) and [*g++ 9.1.0*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uPD4o0UmKRUG17jy) (compilation flags are `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`):

```
template <typename>
struct Base
{
};

struct Derived : Base<int>
{
    Base base()
    {
        return Base();
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

Is it a bug in these compilers or a feature of the C++ standard?

Comment: The important thing to realize is that Base<T> is a class, not a templated class. The compiler uses the template to build a class, where typename T is replaced with the templated parameter. So, Base<typename T> is a template, but Base<int> is a class generated by the template. That means you can use Base<int> anywhere you would normally use a class. This includes variable declarations or, as you found out, inheritance.

Comment: @Chipster I think you have missed the words "...without template arguments" in the question.

Comment: The code you posted used them, so yes. I must have misunderstood. Are you asking why it's okay that the code you posted compiles, or why another snippet can or can't compile?

Comment: @Chipster No, the code I posted doesn't use them. Look at the definition of the method `Derived::base()`.

Comment: Ah. I got you now. Somehow I missed that part. I assumed it was a question about inheritance. I assumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code is fine. Inside `Derived` class `Base` will refer to `Base<int>`, **because** `Derived` inherits from `Base<int>`. Yes, it's legal.

Standard:

> 14.6.1.1: 
>   Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected-class-name can be used as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent to the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>.

Also:

> 3.4.3: The injected-class-name of a class (Clause 9) is also considered to be a member of that class for the purposesof name hiding and lookup.

The last sentence does it. In short `A<B>` introduces hidden "alias" `A = A<B>` but only if `A` is used without `<>`. In an example it's introduced in base class and derived class inherits all members of base class.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the standard?

Comment: I'd also add [\[basic.lookup\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#3) which implies injected-class-name is inherit like other public members.

Answer (score 11):

With [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

Inside `Base<T>`, `Base` refers (in some conditions) to `Base<T>`.

`Derived` would then uses that injected-class-name too.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it works only in templated context, not within classes derived from explicit class template specializations.